# on clicking on delete button everything deletes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
  $(".delete").click(function () {
               $(".delete").parent().remove();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskCont">

        <div class="todoCont">
            <h2>todo</h2>
            <div class="tasks" id="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory" class="getCategory">Coding</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">12:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Practice Javascript</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="completedTaskCont">
            <h2>completed</h2>
            <div class="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" checked>
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory">Shopping</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">10:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Bazar India</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

In this code when I click on delete it deletes all. How to fix this problem?
It's a todo list code. I tried to solve using for loop, but didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following:

```js
$(".delete").click(function () {
// This will delete the parent of element being clicked
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```js
  $(".delete").click(function () {
               $(this).parent().remove();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskCont">

        <div class="todoCont">
            <h2>todo</h2>
            <div class="tasks" id="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory" class="getCategory">Coding</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">12:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Practice Javascript</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="completedTaskCont">
            <h2>completed</h2>
            <div class="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" checked>
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory">Shopping</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">10:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Bazar India</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's dangerous to go with class alone. Take "this":

```js
  $(".delete").click(function () {
               $(this).parent().remove();
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskCont">

        <div class="todoCont">
            <h2>todo</h2>
            <div class="tasks" id="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox">
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory" class="getCategory">Coding</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">12:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Practice Javascript</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="completedTaskCont">
            <h2>completed</h2>
            <div class="tasks">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" checked>
                <div class="cat_time">
                    <h3 id="getCategory">Shopping</h3>
                    <p id="getTime">10:30 AM</p>
                </div>
                <span id="getDescription">Bazar India</span>
                <p class="delete">Delete</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Because what you wrote tells the page to delete the parent of ALL the ".delete", whereas you want just the element clicked ($(this)).

Answer (score 0):

you are calling on all elements with `delete` class and performing on all of them the chained actions. Another possible syntax would be calling the target element on the `click event` object : `$(event.target).parent().remove()`.